# How do I use a function as pipe into an HTML template?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-pipe

I have a bunch of function from a library that I want use into an HTML template as a pipe.
My approach is write a pipe and call the function inside transform method, e.g.:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { awesomeMethod } from 'awesome-library';

@Pipe({ name: 'awesomeMethod' })
export class AwesomeMethodPipe implements PipeTransform {
  public transform(value: any) {
    return awesomeMethod(value);
  }
}
```

I'm searching for some way so that I don't have to implement a new pipe every time. Is there something in Angular for transforming a method into a pipe without write the pipe boilerplate?

E.g. some magic like "provide -> useFactory":

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { awesomeMethod } from 'awesome-library';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyComponent
  ],
  imports: [],
  providers: [
    { provide: 'awesomeMethod', useFactory: (value) => awesomeMethod(value) }
  ]
})
export class MyModule {}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use either of the following methods

using function reference as argument

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'customCallback'
})
export class CustomCallbackPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: string, func: any): string {
    return func(value);
  }

}
```

HTML

```
<div>{{ 'kelum' | customCallback: test }}</div>
```

TS

```
  test(value: string) {
    return 'test ' + value;
  }
```

use a switch within your pipe as follows

```
   @Pipe({
      name: 'pipeFilter',
      pure: false,
    })
    export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
      constructor(private service: TestService) {}
    
      transform(value: string, method: string): string {
        if (method) {
          return this.service[method](value);
        } else {
          return value;
        }
    
        // OR you can do as follows
    
        // switch (method) {
        //   case 'method1':
        //     return this.service.method1(value);
        //   case 'method2':
        //     return this.service.method2(value);
        //   default:
        //     return value;
        // }
      }
    }
```

HTML

```
<div>{{ 'kelum' | pipeFilter }}</div>
<div>{{ 'kelum' | pipeFilter: 'method1' }}</div>
<div>{{ 'kelum' | pipeFilter: 'method2' }}</div>
```

Sample [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/custom-pipes-example-ql8ct6?file=app%2Fapp.component.html,app%2Fcustom.pipe.ts,app%2Ftest.service.ts,app%2Fapp.module.ts,app%2Fapp.component.ts,app%2Fapp.component.scss)